# Subtracting 1 month from array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, pickadate

The date picker I am using is zero indexed, it displays the "wrong date" by 1 month. So I need to correct for that. I am trying to build an array of dates in the following format and then correct for the bug in the date picker (subtract 1 month) and then insert it into the date picker. Here is the code that I have written so far but that only works with a string, not an array.

Example of what I want to do:

```
var array = [
        new Date("11/28/2019"),
        new Date("12/25/2019"),
        new Date("01/01/2020"),
        new Date("01/20/2020"),
        new Date("02/17/2020"),
        new Date("05/25/2020"),
        new Date("07/04/2020"),
        new Date("09/07/2020"),
        new Date("11/26/2020"),
        new Date("12/25/2020"),
        ];

fixeddates.setMonth(array.getMonth() - 1);
```

But I need fixeddates to output an array in this format: [yyyy, m, d]

So essentially I need to subtract 1 month to all those dates and change the format to the date picker accepted format.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting bug. Especially with dates 29, 30 and 31 that aren't present in all months. You can use getFullYear, getMonth and getDate of an data object to extract the values. Note that getMonth is zero-based: 0 = January.

Comment: Why are you using `new Date("11/28/2019")` at all? You should be using `new Date(2019, 10, 28)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "map" through the array to change each row into another object. In this case, I am converting each date to an array of (yyyy, mm, dd). Date.getMonth() already returns the value minus 1, so I didn't decrement it again.

```js
var array = [
        new Date("11/28/2019"),
        new Date("12/25/2019"),
        new Date("01/01/2020"),
        new Date("01/20/2020"),
        new Date("02/17/2020"),
        new Date("05/25/2020"),
        new Date("07/04/2020"),
        new Date("09/07/2020"),
        new Date("11/26/2020"),
        new Date("12/25/2020"),
        ];

var fixedDates = array.map(function(date) {
  return [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()]
});
console.log(fixedDates);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. The only other question I have is how would I go about inserting a "1," before that array? For example I want the output to look like this: [1, [2019, 10, 28],[2019, 11, 25],etc.]"

Comment: The result is an array of arrays. So, you can use the Array function, `unshift` for that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift . `fixedDates.unshift(1)` should do what you need. Or you can do `fixedDates = [1].concat(array.map(...))`